# Invalid identifier when doing a sub select in an outer join

Tags: oracle

I have this SQL statement that I changed because I was getting ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery as I need the join to be an outer join. However, I now get ORA-00904: "A"."DUR": invalid identifier. Not sure how else I could write this any suggestions would be great. I have tried moving the AND B2.EFFDT<A.DUR) to the on clause but then I don't get the correct data back.

```
CALL SP_DROP_TABLE ('PHY_T_FC_TL_REPORTED_TM_B1');
--GO
CREATE TABLE PHY_T_FC_TL_REPORTED_TM_B1 AS (
SELECT
A.DUR                                                AS DD_TM_REPORT_DT
,A.PUNCH_DTTM                                         AS DD_PUNCH_DTTM
,A.PUNCH_END                                          AS DD_PUNCH_END_DTTM
,A.LASTUPDDTTM                                        AS DD_LAST_UPDATE_DTTM
,A.SIGNED_DTTM                                        AS DD_LAST_SIGNED_DTTM
,A.PUNCH_TIME                                         AS DD_PUNCH_TM
,A.EMPL_RCD                                           AS DD_EMPLOYEE_RCD_NUM
,A.SEQ_NBR                                            AS DD_SEQ_NUM
,A.ST_INSTANCE                                        AS DD_SESS_NUM
,A.TL_QUANTITY                                        AS TL_QTY
,A.OVERRIDE_RATE                                      AS OVERRIDE_RATE
,1                                                    AS CNT
,A.DUR                                           AS DT_LOOKUP
,CFG.RUN_DT                                           AS DT_INSERT
,CFG.RUN_DT                                           AS DT_LAST_UPDATE
,A.EMPLID                                             AS K_EMPLOYEE_ID
,A.EMPL_RCD                                           AS K_EMPLOYEE_RCD_NUM
,A.DUR                                                AS K_TM_REPORT_DT
,A.SEQ_NBR                                            AS K_SEQ_NUM
,A.EMPLID                                             AS L_EMPLOYEE_ID
,A.EMPL_RCD                                           AS L_EMPLOYEE_RCD_NUM
,A.DUR                                                AS L_TIME_REPORT_DT
,A.SEQ_NBR                                            AS L_SEQ_NUM
,A.PUNCH_TYPE                                         AS L_PUNCH_TYPE
,A.OVERRIDE_RSN_CD                                    AS L_OVERRIDE_REASON_CD
,A.REPORTED_STATUS                                    AS L_REPORTED_STAT
,A.OPRID                                              AS L_OPR_ID
,A.BUSINESS_UNIT                                      AS L_BUS_UNIT
,A.SETID_LOCATION                                     AS L_SET_ID_LOCATION
,A.LOCATION                                           AS L_LOCATION_CD
,A.SETID_DEPT                                         AS L_SET_ID_DEPT
,A.DEPTID                                             AS L_DEPT_ID
,A.SETID_JOBCODE                                      AS L_SET_ID_JOB_CD
,A.JOBCODE                                            AS L_JOB_CD
,A.POSITION_NBR                                       AS L_POSITION_NUM
,A.BUSINESS_UNIT_PC                                   AS L_PC_BUS_UNIT
,A.PROJECT_ID                                         AS L_PROJ
,A.SETID_ACTIVITY                                     AS L_SET_ID_ACTIVITY_ID
,A.ACTIVITY_ID                                        AS L_ACTIVITY_ID
,A.RESOURCE_TYPE                                      AS L_RESOURCE_TYPE
,A.SETID_RESOURCE                                     AS L_SET_ID_RES
,A.RESOURCE_CATEGORY                                  AS L_RESOURCE_CATG
,A.RESOURCE_SUB_CAT                                   AS L_RESOURCE_SUBCATG
,A.TASK                                               AS L_TASK
,A.USER_FIELD_1                                       AS L_USER_FIELD1
,A.USER_FIELD_2                                       AS L_USER_FIELD2
,A.USER_FIELD_3                                       AS L_USER_FIELD3
,A.USER_FIELD_4                                       AS L_USER_FIELD4
,A.USER_FIELD_5                                       AS L_USER_FIELD5
,A.EMPL_RCD                                           AS L_EMPL_RCD
,A.TASKGROUP                                          AS L_TASK_GRP
,A.TASK_PROFILE_ID                                    AS L_TASK_PROFILE_ID
,A.TRC                                                AS L_TRC
,A.SETID_DEPT                                         AS L_SET_ID
,A.SIGNED_OPRID                                       AS L_OPR_ID_SIGNED
,A.OPRID_LAST_UPDT                                     AS L_OPR_ID_LAST_UPDATE
,coalesce(B4.DEPTID, A.DEPTID,'99') AS L_H_DEPTID
,COALESCE(B4.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, ' ') AS L_H_BUS_UNIT
,COALESCE(B4.POSITION_NBR, A.POSITION_NBR,' ') AS L_H_POS_NBR
FROM PHY_ODS_TL_RPTD_TIME A 

    left outer join (Select * from PHY_ODS_JOB B 
                         Where B.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(EFFDT)
                                              FROM PHY_ODS_JOB B2
                                              WHERE B.EMPLID = B2.EMPLID
                                              AND B.EMPL_RCD = B2.EMPL_RCD
                                              AND B2.EFFDT<A.DUR)
                         AND B.EFFSEQ = (SELECT MAX(EFFSEQ)
                                              FROM PHY_ODS_JOB B3
                                              WHERE B.EMPLID = B3.EMPLID
                                              AND B.EMPL_RCD = B3.EMPL_RCD
                                              AND B.EFFDT = B3.EFFDT)) B4
                        on (
                         B4.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
                         AND B4.EMPL_RCD = A.EMPL_RCD)                                              

, PHY_CFG_RUN_DT CFG
WHERE A.DUR >= (CASE WHEN(SELECT count(1) FROM PHY_S_FC_TL_REPORTED_TM)> 0 THEN (ADD_MONTHS(CFG.RUN_DT,-6)) ELSE (SELECT MIN(PAY.PAY_BEGIN_DT) FROM PHY_ODS_PAY_CALENDAR PAY WHERE PAY_OFF_CYCLE = 'N' AND PAY_END_DT >= TO_DATE(('01-JAN-'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 4)),'DD-MON-YY')) END)
  AND A.DUR <= (SELECT MAX(PAY.PAY_END_DT) FROM PHY_ODS_PAY_CALENDAR PAY WHERE PAY_OFF_CYCLE = 'N' AND CHECK_DT <= CFG.RUN_DT))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer apply` or simple solution will be to move the where clause from subquery to main where clause as follows:

```
..
..
left outer join (Select * from PHY_ODS_JOB B 
                         Where B.EFFSEQ = (SELECT MAX(EFFSEQ)
                                              FROM PHY_ODS_JOB B3
                                              WHERE B.EMPLID = B3.EMPLID
                                              AND B.EMPL_RCD = B3.EMPL_RCD
                                              AND B.EFFDT = B3.EFFDT)) B4
                        on (
                         B4.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
                         AND B4.EMPL_RCD = A.EMPL_RCD)                                             

, PHY_CFG_RUN_DT CFG
WHERE A.DUR >= (CASE WHEN(SELECT count(1) FROM PHY_S_FC_TL_REPORTED_TM)> 0 THEN (ADD_MONTHS(CFG.RUN_DT,-6)) ELSE (SELECT MIN(PAY.PAY_BEGIN_DT) FROM PHY_ODS_PAY_CALENDAR PAY WHERE PAY_OFF_CYCLE = 'N' AND PAY_END_DT >= TO_DATE(('01-JAN-'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 4)),'DD-MON-YY')) END)
  AND A.DUR <= (SELECT MAX(PAY.PAY_END_DT) FROM PHY_ODS_PAY_CALENDAR PAY WHERE PAY_OFF_CYCLE = 'N' AND CHECK_DT <= CFG.RUN_DT)
And ( B4.EFFDT is null or  B4.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(EFFDT)                                             
 FROM PHY_ODS_JOB B2                                             
WHERE B4.EMPLID = B2.EMPLID                                              
  AND B4.EMPL_RCD = B2.EMPL_RCD                                             
  AND B2.EFFDT<A.DUR) )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this still has the effect of an inner join, and I have thousands of rows not being returned. It is strange the original query that I did not post here that was getting a ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery runs fine until I try to do a creat table, or insert into statement.